# when finding whether a character is in a string or not error occurs

Tags: java, string, char

I try to use contains method to find whether a character is in a string or not?
I get the error :

> method contains in class String cannot be applied to given types 
>           if(str.contains(ch))
>           required:CharSequence 
>           found:char

**code :**

```
str1=rs.getString(1);
int len=str1.length();
while(i<len)
{
char ch=str1.charAt(i);
if (str.contains(ch))
continue;
else
str=str+str1.charAt(i);
i++;
}
```

Comment: `String` is defined as an Object using the interface CharSequence. The `char` is a primitive datatype and can not use the interface CharSequence. This causes you to hurt the `String#contains` method signature.

Answer (score 3):

`if ( str.indexOf( ch ) != -1 )` should work.

`String.contains` only accepts a CharSequence, but one Character is not a `CharSequence`. The way above works for Characters, too. Another way, as other people have posted (but I want to explain a little bit more), would be to make your single Character into a CharSequence, for example by creating a String...

```
String x = "" + b; // implicit conversion
String y = Character.valueOf(ch).toString(); // explicit conversion
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `String` has not any overloaded `contains()` method for `char`.
Use the [String.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method for [CharSequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) like -

```
String ch = "b";
str.contains(ch);
```

Her the `CharSequence` is an `interface`. A `CharSequence` is a readable sequence of char values. This interface provides uniform, read-only access to many different kinds of char sequences.
All known implementation of at JDK are: `CharSequence` are - `CharBuffer`, `Segment`, `String`, `StringBuffer`, `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the declaration for `java.lang.String.contains()` method

```
public boolean contains(CharSequence s)
```

So you have to Convert the character to string before passing it to the function

```
 Character ch = 'c';   
 str.contains(ch.toString());//converts ch to string and passes to the function
```

**or**

```
str.contains(ch+"");//converts  ch to string and passes to the function
```

Correct Code

```
    str1=rs.getString(1);
    int len=str1.length();
    while(i<len)
    {
    char ch=str1.charAt(i);
    if (str.contains(ch+""))//changed line
    continue;
    else
    str=str+str1.charAt(i);
    i++;
    }
```

Comment: That's somehow ugly. I would prefer ch.toString() then instead of that implicit conversion.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz mostly o/p might be using "char" instead of "Character".